# Encoding error with Rails, PostgreSQL and non-standard characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, character-encoding

I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xf66e6bf6 : INSERT INTO "response_sets" ("city") VALUES ('Jönköping') RETURNING "id"
```

Database is PostgreSQL 9.0.6 on a Heroku app.

Not sure how to get around that error when there are odd characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your database isn't set to the same encoding scheme as the string you're trying to insert. I would imagine Postgres on Heroku is set up to use UTF-8 by default and your input might be one of the latin variations if I had to guess. You can either set your database to accept the encoding scheme you're supplying, e.g.:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING 'ISO-8859-2'
```

Or you can transcode your input to UTF-8 (this is probably better)

```
"my string".encode('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

It's likely your database isn't set to the same encoding as the string you're inserting.  Postgres is typically UTF-8.
You'll have to set the proper encoding on your string.
That could be as simple as

```
"string".encode('UTF-8')
```

Or if the string is improperly tagged you may also have to force_encoding first.  ie. it's stored as 'Windows-1252' but not marked as such by Ruby.

```
"string".force_encoding('Windows-1252').encode('UTF-8')
```

We had this problem working with Sendgrid + Heroku Rails
http://blog.zenlike.me/2013/04/06/sendgrid-parse-incoming-email-encoding-errors-for-rails-apps-using-postgresql/

Comment: The force_encoding was the magic ingredient I needed to fix the error. I was also using Sendgrid + Heroku Rails, specifically using their Parse function for incoming emails (on their :text and :html params)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
"Hern\xE1ndez".encode('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1')
```

The first argument is the encoding that you want the string to be in and the second argument is the encoding that you think the string is in.

[String#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-encode)

There are also options in the documentation on how to deal with invalid or undefined characters.

This is what I ended up using (just to be safe):

```
"Hern\xE1ndez".encode('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
```

You can also make up a helper method:

```
def convert_to_utf_8(string)
  string.encode('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
end
```

The problem I was having was loading data from the Amazon Merchant Services API.